# How to resolve these warnings in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I cant understand the nature of this problem. I provide stacktrace what i've got:

```
kestrel.service - ASP.NET Core Application running on Ubuntu
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-08-29 14:34:18 BRT; 7s ago
 Main PID: 2356 (dotnet)
    Tasks: 25
   Memory: 173.9M
      CPU: 6.913s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kestrel.service
           └─2356 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/publish/Abp.Web.Mvc.dll

Aug 29 14:34:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started ASP.NET Core Application running on Ubuntu.
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]: : Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]:       Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]:       Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will b
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]:       Creating key {2a2891cb-5852-4f47-9b1b-c97850fc05cc} with creation date 2017-08-29 17:34:20Z, activation da
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
Aug 29 14:34:20 ubuntu dotnet-example[2356]:       No XML encryptor configured. Key {2a2891cb-5852-4f47-9b1b-c97850fc05cc} may be persisted to storage in une
~
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal when the introspection endpoint receives a token, it has to determine whether it's an access token, an identity token, an authorization code or a refresh token by trying to deserialize it. In this case, the OIDC server middleware tried to read the token as an identity token and failed to do so (which is expected, since the token is likely an access token).To configure Data Protection and ensure the key ring is shared between your instances

for more info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview